# ADODB - VBA - MySQL - SHOW TABLES Syntax

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, adodb

I have a connection through VBA to a MySQL database but I can't determine the proper syntax to return the values from a SHOW TABLES query.

```
Dim rs As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sqlstr As String
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)  
sqlstr = "SHOW TABLES"

Call connectDatabase
rs.Open sqlstr, DBCONT

For i = 0 To (rs.RecordCount - 1)
    ws.Cells(i+1, 1).value = rs(i)
    rs.movenext
Next i

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Call closeDatabase
```

The error statement reads as:

> Run-time error '3265' - Item cannot be found in the collection
>   corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.

This exact same code works perfectly when I am trying to view the results from a "`SHOW COLUMNS FROM tableName`" query and also from a "`SELECT columnName1 FROM tableName`" query. I assume the error is that the Table names are not supposed to return as a Recordset???

As requested, this is how I connect to my database:

```
Public DBCONT As Object

Public Function connectDatabase()
    Set DBCONT = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim Port As String
    Dim sConn As String

    Server_Name = "localhost"
    Database_Name = "databaseName"
    User_ID = "userID"
    Password = "password"
    Port = "3306"

    sConn = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=" & _
                Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
                ";UID=" & User_ID & ";PWD=" & Password & ";Option=3;"

    DBCONT.Open sConn
    DBCONT.cursorlocation = 3

End Function
```

This is how I close my database:

```
Public Function closeDatabase()
    On Error Resume Next 
    DBCONT.Close
    Set DBCONT = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: In general, you could replace the whole For..Next loop with `ws.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs` Not sure if it would help with this specific error though

Comment: COuld you show how you `connectDatabase` ?

Comment: barrowc - Your suggestion solved my problem! If you put this down as an answer I can mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by barrowc in the comments:

In general, you could replace the whole For..Next loop with `ws.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs` Not sure if it would help with this specific error though – barrowc Apr 8 at 23:54